# Overloaded versions of WriteLine; why not use generics/template?

Tags: c#

> The `System.Console` type offers several overloaded versions of the `WriteLine` method (Boolean, `Char`, `Int32`)

so basically the sentence is saying when implementing Writeline for different primitive types, they overloaded the function a couple of times.
Instead of writing so many functions for different types, why don't they use generics / templating ?

If it is in c++, I would assume templating in such scenarios are better solutions compared with overloaded versions of similar functions. don't know the incentive here.

next line:
for the sole purpose of reducing number of boxing operations for the common value types ...

how does these reduce boxing count then? constructing the string directly instead of calling `ToString` ?

Comment: This is essentially equivalent to "why `printf` does not use C++ templates"... (see Marco's answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics were introduced in 2005, those methods were available before. They could still add them now but I guess it is not worth the trouble and changing them would break the compatibility chain, but I guess in this case it is more convenient as it stands.

Comment: they should add one actually, because the self defined value type still need to be boxed when called upon this writeline method

Answer (score 0):

As Marco says, the overloads pre-date Generics.

My gut feeling also says that the performance gain from removing boxing operations is likely to be negligible compared to the cost of dealing with the Console. This will be especially true for any blocking that occurs due to buffering.

Comment: That might be a bad assumption.  Console could be connected to anything, perhaps an efficient custom TextWriter

Comment: That's one of the reasons I said "gut feeling", because it depends what's on the other side of the Console. But that also implies that what's on the other side of the Console could be a slow implementation that fills up a buffer quickly and blocks writing. If I was writing some highly efficient logging/output/message sending, I wouldn't bother sending it through the Console.

Comment: The point being you need to understand the performance of the Console reader to understand whether the boxing is significant. Unless you're doing something highly specialized, I'd say the answer is likely "no".